# Why is my count() returning 1 when it's empty?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Trying to return information from a Database (Which is empty). It keep returning the value of 1 however it should be 0. The database is empty but is returning "I exist".

```
       <?php

set_time_limit(0);

$db = new mysqli("localhost","wwwrhino_Twitch","","wwwrhino_Twitch");

if($db->connect_errno) {
    echo $db->connect_error;
    die('Sorry, We are having some problems');
}


$offset = 0;
$count = 1;

do {
    $Brad = json_decode(file_get_contents(
        'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/greatbritishbg/follows?limit=25&offset='  . $offset
    )); 
    $Darren = json_decode(file_get_contents(
        'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/Skairpigg/follows?limit=25&offset='  . $offset
    )); 



    foreach($Brad->follows as $Bradfollow) {
        $username = (string)$Bradfollow->user->name;
    //$result = $db->query("SELECT count(Username) FROM `Users` WHERE `Username` ='$username' ");
    $result = $db->query("SELECT count(Username) AS total_users FROM `Users` WHERE `Username` ='$username' ");
    if ($result->total_users > 0) {
        echo 'I Exist!: '. (int)$result . ": " . $username . "<br>";     
        var_dump($result);
    }
    else { 
        echo 'Add me'; 
        echo "<p>Inserting Value:". $username ."</p>";
        echo "Var Dump:" . var_dump($result);
            if($insert = $db->query("
        INSERT INTO Users (Username, Minecraft_Name) 
        VALUES ('$username', 'Garrett')
        ")) {
        echo $db->affected_rows . "<br>";
        }
    }
    $offset+=25;
} while (!empty($Brad->follows));
?>
```

Here is my database:

[image]

Can anyone explain why the result is constantly returning as "1"

Thanks

Comment: Because `$result` is not even a number. `var_dump()` it and see that it's not equal to `1`

Comment: You do not check the fetched row

Comment: @zerkms I tried var_dump($result). Came out as 1.

Comment: @Bradly Spicer: documentation does not agree with you http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: updated my answer. hope now it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using mysqli and the proper way is -

```
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM test ORDER BY id ASC");

echo "Reverse order...\n";
for ($row_no = $res->num_rows - 1; $row_no >= 0; $row_no--) {
    $res->data_seek($row_no);
    $row = $res->fetch_assoc();
    echo " id = " . $row['id'] . "\n";
}
```

reference - [phpmanual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php)

try with -

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT count(Username) AS total_users FROM `Users` WHERE `Username` ='$username' ");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

and for making it sure you can try to `dump` the `$row` and see what it is returning. then check with proper `index`-

```
if ($row['total_users'] > 0) {
    //your code
}
```

you were only executing the query which was returning `true` or `1` always. you have to fetch the data also from the resource.

Comment: "it is returning array with index" --- it's unlikely

Comment: that query will return an array with index `count(Username)`.

Comment: Yes, but certainly not this way. $result will be a resource on which you will have to use fetch_assoc or something to access the data. Only this data will be an array.

Comment: know that & updated the answer. i think `$db->query` will return an object as the code is showing, no need for fetching againg.

Comment: may i know the reason for -1 ?

Comment: @sgt I tried your method, Thanks for fixing up the $result->total_users. I had done that before I used your previous snippet :P It's still not detecting that the entry is already in the database.

Comment: try to dump the `$result` and see what you are getting.

Comment: are you using any query builder?? or can you post the code of `query()`?

Comment: @sgt this isn't using any tools or anything. I'l update OP with the whole script.

Comment: @sgt Makes sense! Thanks for sticking with me and not being all cryptic. Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT count(Username) as cnt FROM `Users` WHERE `Username` ='$username' ");
$row = $result->result();
if ($row->cnt > 0) {
    echo 'I Exist!: '. (int)$result . ": " . $username . "<br>"; 
 }
```

[Reference](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html).

Comment: not sure $result->result(); will work as I'm not using ->result() in my foreach. I'm using the Twitch API so it's like so:     $Brad = json_decode(file_get_contents(
        'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/greatbritishbg/follows?limit=25&offset='  . $offset
    ));